# Python break list values into sub-components and maintain key

Tags: python, tuples

Hello I have a list as follows:

```
['2925729', 'Patrick did not shake our hands nor ask our names. He greeted us promptly and politely, but it seemed routine.'].
```

My goal is a result as follows:

```
['2925729','Patrick did not shake our hands nor ask our names'], ['2925729', 'He greeted us promptly and politely, but it seemed routine.']
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just a minor detail; isn't that a `list` instead of a `tuple`? ;)

Comment: Lol yes you are right. I guess to keep it simple let's stick with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> t = ['2925729', 'Patrick did not shake our hands nor ask our names. He greeted us promptly and politely, but it seemed routine.']
>>> [ [t[0], a + '.'] for a in t[1].rstrip('.').split('.')]
[['2925729', 'Patrick did not shake our hands nor ask our names.'], ['2925729', ' He greeted us promptly and politely, but it seemed routine.']]
```

If you have a large dataset and want to conserve memory, you may want to create a generator instead of a list:

```
g = ( [t[0], a + '.'] for a in t[1].rstrip('.').split('.') )
for key, sentence in g:
    # do processing
```

Generators do not create lists all at once.  They create each element as you access it.  This is only helpful if you don't need the whole list at once.

ADDENDUM: You asked about making dictionaries if you have multiple keys:

```
>>> data = ['1', 'I think. I am.'], ['2', 'I came. I saw. I conquered.']
>>> dict([ [t[0], t[1].rstrip('.').split('.')] for t in data ])
{'1': ['I think', ' I am'], '2': ['I came', ' I saw', ' I conquered']}
```

Comment: Thank you John. Is there a dynamic way to go about this if i had a large data set in the same structure?

Comment: @user3116753  I just added a bit on generators that, if your needs allow, would help conserve memory for large datasets.  Is that what you meant by "dynamic"?

Comment: Thank you John. In the instance of needing the entire list at once how can I proceed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In that case, use the first form in my answer above: `answer = [ [t[0], a + '.'] for a in t[1].rstrip('.').split('.') ]`

Comment: actually i have another question. I was considering converting to a dictionary but dictionaries have unique keys. How do i go about this?

Comment: So, what do you want to do with the repeated keys?  Keep the first sentence, the last sentence, or combine the sentences for that key into a list?

Comment: Well I do not necessarily need the duplicated keys so far as there is a pythonic way to find all sentences from a given user. Is there a way to go about it please?