# Convert list into sub-list while maintaining "key"

Tags: python, list, key, tuples

I have a list that contains a 'key' and 'paragraph'. Each 'key' is associated with a 'paragraph'.

My goal is to break each paragraph into individual sentences, with each sentence being assign to the 'key' they originally belonged to in paragraph form. For example:

```
(['2925729', 'Patrick came outside and greeted us promptly.'], ['2925729', 'Patrick did not shake our hands nor ask our names. He greeted us promptly and politely, but it seemed routine.'], ['2925728', 'Patrick sucks. He farted politely, but it seemed routine.'])
```

Right now I've been able to write code to break out sentences into paragraphs, and get the number of hits for each sentence against a dictionary. I now want to associate an ID to each question.

Here is the code that deals with sentences without any 'key'. Step1 and 2 I omitted for space conservation:

```
Dictionary = ['book', 'should have', 'open']

####Step3#####
#Create Blank list to append final output
final_out = []

##Find Matches
for sent in sentences:
  for sent in sentences:
      final_out.append((sent, sum(sent.count(col) for col in dictionary)))

#####Spit out final distinct output
##Output in dictionary structure
final_out = dict(sorted(set(final_out)))

####Get sentences and rank by max first

import operator
sorted_final_out = sorted(final_out.iteritems(),key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

The output from this is: 
***(['johny ate the antelope', 80], ['sally has a friend',20])*** and so on. I then pick the top X b magnitude. What I am now trying to achieve is something like this: **(['12222','johny ate the antelope', 80], [22332,'sally has a friend',20])**. So i basically want to ensure that all sentences when parsed out are assigned to a 'key'. This is complicated sorry. Again that is why John's earlier solution would work on a simpler case.

Comment: Can you post the code you are talking about? And the expected output please.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849134/python-break-list-values-into-sub-components-and-maintain-key

Comment: What's wrong with the answer you accepted?

Comment: It answers the question but the result is partial with a larger more complex dataset. I didn't want to not credit John for the response because in fact he answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[[[y[0],z] for z in y[1].split('. ')] for y in x]))
```

produces

```
[['2925729', 'Patrick came outside and greeted us promptly.'],
 ['2925729', 'Patrick did not shake our hands nor ask our names'],
 ['2925729', 'He greeted us promptly and politely, but it seemed routine.'],
 ['2925728', 'Patrick sucks'],
 ['2925728', 'He farted politely, but it seemed routine.']]
```

`list(chain(*...))` flattens the nested list produced by `[[[y[0],z] for z in y[1].split('. ')] for y in x]`.

If you'd rather change list 'in place' you could use

```
xl = list(x) # you gave us a tuple          
for i,y in enumerate(xl):
    xx = xl[i]
    xx = [[xx[0],y] for y in xx[1].split('. ')]
    xl[i:i+1] = xx
```

I'm not sure which would work faster or better when the data set is very large.

Comment: Thank you hpaul. This works as intended. I might have a few follow up questions. I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Hpaul. What if I had another field between the key and the sentences? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean like: `[[xx[0], xx[1], y] for y in xx[2].split('. ')]`?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. The expected output is something like: ['2893357', 'SUPER', 'sesame street.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'The books are all open.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'I saw no trash or debris.']
['2893357', 'SUPER', 'She was clean and well organized.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"I stopped and turned it off.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"He was smiling.']
['2893357', 'STELLAR', '"He welcomed me to See and asked how he was able to assist me that day.']. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your input is now: `(['2893357','SUPER','ses...'],['2893357','STELLAR','I stop...'])`